# Ducted A/C system under powered

Tags: hvac

I recently replaced carpets with tiles in my apartment, and in the process generated an incredible amount of dust.

All this dust was sucked into my A/C ducting, and the filters in the return were completely blocked.

I've replaced all the filters, but am convinced that the performance is significantly lower than before.

It is a double story apartment, has only one single zone, and the controller is upstairs. The temperature on the controller is reading the correct temperature (and therefore the system shuts off), but downstairs feels notably warmer than it did before.

Could the excessive dust have blocked anything else?

Is there anything I can do myself to confirm the system is working as expected?

Comment: Maybe the dust lowered the air flow enough to allow an ice buildup on the coils. That happened to me when i was refinishing hardwood floors. Turn off the AC for 12 hours and then resume normal operation.

Comment: @dandavis thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fine dust particles can slip through the filter and cake up on the coil which is constantly creating moisture.

Once it is clogged the air flow will be diminished and because of that the air that gets through will be very cold. Eventually it will ice up and burn your fan motor out.

There are specific steps that need to be followed to clean the coil safely and effectively. I’d call a pro out for a service call and tell that human what happened.

Comment: The dust blocks the air flow, no flow the coils ice up further reduces the flow. Since you have some flow the evaporator coin inside the air handler needs a good cleaning. This is recommended to be done once a year by most mfg’s

Comment: Thanks both, will definitely call in a pro